# Average value of double integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to work on this homework problem but I am lost. The only thing I know to do here is divide the double integral by 8 or multiply by 1/8 since area = l*w and 4*2=8.

But now, please help me understand how I can convert the C to x and y and get the bounds for integration. I want to understand it so if you can explain it then I would be happy.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: The image isn’t entirely clear, but it appears that the formula is $$C(x,y)=100-15d^2\;.$$ Use the Pythagorean theorem: $d^2=x^2+y^2$, so $$C(x,y)=100-15x^2-15y^2\;.$$

Comment: Okay then what about the bounds? could the bounds be 0,2 for both x and y? or 0,2 for x and 0,4 for y?

Comment: @Raynos: You want to cover the **whole** rectangle. What are the smallest and largest $x$ values? The smallest and largest $y$ values?

Comment: -2,2 for x and -1,1 for y

Comment: so basically I plug in the concentration formula and integrate with the bounds and then divide by 8 to get average value. Is that right?

Comment: @Raynos: That’s right, and so are your bounds for $x$ and $y$. What you’re doing with the integration is ‘adding up’ the total concentration over the rectangle; dividing by the area then gives you the average concentration per unit area.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it.

Comment: @Raynos: You’re very welcome.